# twig: How to add Twig extension file whilst NOT using symfony

Tags: php, twig

I am currently using v1.12.2 Twig as a standalone templating engine.

I wrote a Twig extension called Utility_Twig_Extension in a file called UtilityExtension.php

and an index.php

```
//index.php
require_once '../vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(OEBPS);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => APP . DS . 'cache',
));

require_once '../vendor/twig/twig/ext/utility/UtilityExtension.php';

$twig->addExtension(new Utility_Twig_Extension());
```

Here is the UtilityExtension.php
    //UtilityExtension.php
    namespace UtilityTwigExtension;

```
class Utility_Twig_Extension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return "utility";
    }

}
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
src
 |__app
 |    |__ index.php
 |__vendor
      |__twig
           |__twig
               |__ext
               |__lib
```

I cannot even load the file properly.

I have traced the issue to the fact that the extension class tries to extend Twig_Extension.php.

So I `require_once` the Twig_Extension which is the Extension.php file in UtilityExtension.php. However, still not working.

Most documentation talks about adding a custom Twig Extension in the context of Symfony.

I am using Twig standalone, so I have yet to find any documentation on that.

Please advise.

**UPDATE1:**

By not working, I meant that I get the 500 server error. I ran error_reporting(E_ALL) was to no avail.

The error was relieved the moment I removed the words `extends Twig_Extension` from the extension class.

**UPDATE2:**
I realized it was a namespace issue. because I removed the  `namespace UtilityTwigExtension;` from the UtilityExtension.php and the server 500 error was gone.

So I put the `namespace UtilityTwigExtension;` back and then call

```
require_once '../vendor/twig/twig/ext/utility/UtilityExtension.php';

$twig->addExtension(new UtilityTwigExtension\Utility_Twig_Extension());
```

the error came back.

Question: How do I call the TwigExtension if I insist on using the namespace? Is there a better way of using namespace?

**UPDATE3:**

I still get server 500 after trying Luceos answer.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'constants.php';

require_once 'ZipLib.php';

require_once '../vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(OEBPS);

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => APP . DS . 'cache',
));

require_once '../vendor/twig/twig/ext/utility/UtilityExtension.php';

use UtilityTwigExtension\Utility_Twig_Extension;

$twig->addExtension(new Utility_Twig_Extension());
```

the UtilityExtension.php

```
namespace UtilityTwigExtension;

class Utility_Twig_Extension extends Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'utility';
    }

}
```

Comment: [This page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html) on the Twig website shows you how to do it and doesn't mention symfony. First Google result for "Twig add extension"

Comment: I followed the steps there. unless I overlooked something?

Comment: Yes but you realize your extension doesn't actually _do_ anything, right? How do you know it's not being loaded? "It's not working" _is not helpful_.

Comment: ```namespace UtilityTwigExtension```? Did you create the UtilityTwigExtension in its own namespace? You would then need to add the extension:

```$twig->addExtension(new UtilityTwigExtension\Utility_Twig_Extension());```

Comment: @ColinMorelli I apologize. I meant that I had a server 500 error. I have made the corrections.

Comment: @kimsia As Luceos posted above - are you using the namespace when you load the class?

Comment: Ah.. it turns out to be a namespace issue. How do I correctly call it? I used $twig->addExtension(new UtilityTwigExtension\Utility_Twig_Extension()); but still have errors

Comment: you can also try:

```use UtilityTwigExtension\Utility_Twig_Extension;```
and then call:
```$twig->addExtension(new Utility_Twig_Extension());```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's put the comments in an answer and move on from there without crowding the comments:

First of call the extension from the correct namespace:

```
use UtilityTwigExtension\Utility_Twig_Extension;
$twig->addExtension(new Utility_Twig_Extension());
```

Use and namespaces calls are normally placed at the top of the file.

You can also try calling the namespace + object directly by using:

`$twig->addExtension(new UtilityTwigExtension\Utility_Twig_Extension());`

**Update 3**

The Utility_Twig_Extension extends Twig_Extension from the namespace UtilityTwigExtension, which does not exist. I assume Twig_Extension is not in any namespace so you'll use \Twig_Extension:

```
namespace UtilityTwigExtension;

class Utility_Twig_Extension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'utility';
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your answer. But didn't work out. UPDATE3 lists my changes.

Comment: I have been using namespaces for a very short time now, but I absolutely see the sense of it. So if you can, try to use it as much as you can; especially with larger projects.